# Caml query - Created By AND Title OR Comments OR Status

Tags: caml

Can someone please help me with this caml query? I have a list view and the list view should only return items created by the current user. Then I also have a textbox to provide values for Title and Comments. I am not sure why the following caml doesn't work?

```
<Query> <Where>
  <Or>
     <Or>
        <And>
           <Eq>
              <FieldRef Name='Author' />
              <Value Type='Integer'>
                 <UserID />
              </Value>
           </Eq>
           <Eq>
              <FieldRef Name='Title' />
              <Value Type='Text'>{Param1}</Value>
           </Eq>
        </And>
        <Eq>
           <FieldRef Name='_Comments' />
           <Value Type='Note'>{Param1}</Value>
        </Eq>
     </Or>
     <Contains>
        <FieldRef Name='RequestStatus' />
        <Value Type='Choice'>{Param1}</Value>
     </Contains>
  </Or>
```

{Param1} is an asp:textbox server side control with autopostback set to true.

Thanks in advance for all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you've got there in pseudocode is
Created by User and Title = whatever
OR 
Comments = whatever
OR
Request Status = whatever

Your AND is out of place. And remember to close up your where and query tags.

Remember CAML is based on pairs of statements anded/ored together.

This ors together the title and comment fields.

Then ors that answer with the status field

Then ands that whole thing with the user.

```
<Query> <Where>
    <And>
       <Eq>
          <FieldRef Name='Author' />
          <Value Type='Integer'>
             <UserID />
          </Value>
       </Eq>
       <Or>
            <Or>
               <Eq>
                  <FieldRef Name='Title' />
                  <Value Type='Text'>{Param1}</Value>
               </Eq>
               <Eq>
                   <FieldRef Name='_Comments' />
                   <Value Type='Note'>{Param1}</Value>
               </Eq>
            </Or>
             <Contains>
                <FieldRef Name='RequestStatus' />
                <Value Type='Choice'>{Param1}</Value>
             </Contains>
        </Or>
    </And>
    </Where>
    </Query>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Where>
    <And>
        <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name="Author" LookupId="True" />
            <Value Type="Integer">
                <UserID />
            </Value>
        </Eq>
        <Or>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name="Title" />
                <Value Type="Text">Test 1</Value>
            </Eq>
            <Or>
                <Eq>
                    <FieldRef Name="_Comments" />
                    <Value Type="Text">test</Value>
                </Eq>
                <Contains>
                    <FieldRef Name="RequestStatus" />
                    <Value Type="Choice">A</Value>
                </Contains>
            </Or>
        </Or>
    </And>
</Where>
```